# Killed: 9 Creating a graph from a list of nodes and a list of links

Tags: python, igraph

I am using [iGraph](http://igraph.org/redirect.html) to build a network from a list of `nodes` and a list of `links`. There are a 200,000 nodes and 450,000 links. For each `node` there is some associated meta-data and for each `link` the same.

The nodes list looks like this:

```
[{u'toid': u'osgb4000000031043205', u'index': 1, u'point': [508180.748, 195333.973]}, {u'toid': u'osgb4000000031043206', u'index': 2, u'point': [508163.122, 195316.627]}, {u'toid': u'osgb4000000031043207', u'index': 3, u'point': [508172.075, 195325.719]}, {u'toid': u'osgb4000000031043208', u'index': 4, u'point': [508513, 196023]}]
```

The `links` list looks like this:

```
[{u'index': 1, u'term': u'Private Road - Restricted Access', u'nature': u'Single Carriageway', u'negativeNode': u'osgb4000000023183407', u'toid': u'osgb4000000023296573', u'polyline': [492019.481, 156567.076, 492028, 156567, 492041.667, 156570.536, 492063.65, 156578.067, 492126.5, 156602], u'positiveNode': u'osgb4000000023183409'}, {u'index': 2, u'term': u'Private Road - Restricted Access', u'nature': u'Single Carriageway', u'negativeNode': u'osgb4000000023763485', u'toid': u'osgb4000000023296574', u'polyline': [492144.493, 156762.059, 492149.35, 156750, 492195.75, 156630], u'positiveNode': u'osgb4000000023183408'}, {u'index': 3, u'term': u'Private Road - Restricted Access', u'nature': u'Single Carriageway', u'negativeNode': u'osgb4000000023183650', u'toid': u'osgb4000000023296638', u'polyline': [492835.25, 156873.5, 493000, 156923, 493018.061, 156927.938], u'positiveNode': u'osgb4000000023183652'}, {u'index': 4, u'term': u'Local Street', u'nature': u'Single Carriageway', u'negativeNode': u'osgb4000000023181163', u'toid': u'osgb4000000023388466', u'polyline': [498136.506, 149148.313, 498123.784, 149143.969, 498119.223, 149143.411, 498116.43, 149143.318, 498113.638, 149145.179], u'positiveNode': u'osgb4000000023806248'}]
```

I attempt to build the graph:

```
g = Graph()

# Add nodes (and associated data)
for node in nodes:
    g.add_vertices(node['toid'])
# Add links (and associated data)
for link in links:
    g.add_edges([(link['negativeNode'],link['positiveNode'])])
```

The links file includes a small amount of cases where a negativeNode or positiveNode is not found in the nodes list. As such, iGraph throws the following error:

```
ValueError: no such vertex: u'osgb4000000019779815'
```

I attempted to add those `nodes` from the link file that did not exist in the `nodes` list.

```
for node in nodes:
    for link in links:
        if link['negativeNode'] not in node['toid']:
            missing_dict = {
            "toid": link['negativeNode']
            }
            nodes.append(missing_dict)
        if link['positiveNode'] not in node['toid']:
            missing_dict = {
            "toid": link['negativeNode']
            }
            nodes.append(missing_dict)
```

However, this resulted in the following error:

```
Killed: 9
```

I believe the process was using too much memory. How should I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your second attempt would try to add the same link multiple times; in the worst case, the last link in your `links` vector might get added as many times as there are nodes in the `nodes` vector. So, that approach won't work.

Second, igraph is not very efficient when you add nodes or edges one by one (due to the indexing operation that it performs after every node addition or removal). It is best to add them in "batches", i.e. prepare multiple nodes or edges to add and then add them at once with a single call to `add_vertices()` or `add_edges()`.

Third, the `Graph.DictList()` method is designed explicitly for your purpose: it takes two lists of dictionaries, one for the nodes and one for the edges, and then constructs a graph out of them, provided that you tell it which members of the dictionary store the vertex names and the endpoints of the edges:

```
g = Graph.DictList(vertices=nodes, edges=links, vertex_name_attr="toid", edge_foreign_keys=("positiveNode", "negativeNode")
```

All that you need to ensure before calling `Graph.DictList()` is that all the nodes that occur in the edge list are found in the node list:

```
all_node_ids = set(edge["positiveNode"] for edge in links) | set(edge["negativeNode"] for edge in links)
known_node_ids = set(node["toid"] for node in nodes)
for node in all_node_ids - known_node_ids:
    nodes.append({u'toid': node})
```

Comment: Thank you! I see your first point now. I was not aware of the DictList method, excellent. I am attempting to run the code you suggested but I am getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'` for the `all_node_ids` line. I have not used `set` in Python before so I am trying to understand this now...

Comment: Ah, I could have sworn that the addition operator works for sets, but it turns out that you need the `|` operator instead. I'm fixing my answer now.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, I think in the case were a link gives a node that doesn't previously exist igraph is automatically handling this. I presume you added this feature recently... I can't see it in the documentation!

Comment: It could be the case because `Graph.DictList` is designed in a way that it works even if you specify only the `edges` array.